# SQL Grouping as a comma-separated list of values in one column

Tags: mysql

I am working on an API to return a list of venues.

```
SELECT 
    `sample`.Fascia AS 'Fascia',
    `sample`.Category AS 'Category'
FROM
    `sample`
WHERE 
    `sample`.`PostCode` LIKE '%SW1%'
```

and this returns a list of venues.

```
Fascia      | Category
------------+-------------
Sainsbury's | Supermarkets
Waitrose    | Supermarkets
99p Store   | Hardware
T K Max     | Clothing
```

How would I modify the query to group the categories together and create an abstract column that lists these venues as a comma list. So something like this

```
Category      | Grouped Venues
--------------+------------------------
Supermarkets  | Sainsbury's, Waitrose
Hardware      | 99p Store
Clothing      | T K Max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Group_concat:

```
        SELECT 
        Group_concat(`sample`.Fascia) AS 'Grouped Venues',
        `sample`.Category AS 'Category'
        FROM
        `sample`
        WHERE `sample`.`PostCode` LIKE '%SW1%'
        Group by `sample`.Category
```